# Узнать ширину окна браузера до ресайза и на сколько она изменилась

Tags: javascript

Есть ли у обьекта window или document свойства с помощью которых можно
узнать ширину окна браузера до ресайза и на сколько она изменилась

Comment: `const winWidthOnStart = window.innerWidth; window.addEventListener('resize', () => { console.log(window.innerWidth -
 winWidthOnStart); });`

Comment: Нужно что бы всякий раз когда меняется ширина браузера можно было получить именно ПРЕДЫДУЩУЮ ширину а не изначальную. Просто я думал что она сохраняется в каком-нибудь свойстве какова-нибудь обьекта типа window или screen или document и т. д.

Comment: что значит "предыдущую"? Предыдущая будет равна текущей, минус пара пикселей, так как изменение происходит на каждое движение. Вам нужно изменение за какой-то промежуток времени? Что такое для вас "предыдущее", если схватить край браузера и начать туда сюда им водить, то что в этом случае будет для вас "начальной точкой отсчета", а что "конечной"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На основе вашего комментария

> Нужно что бы всякий раз когда меняется ширина браузера можно было получить именно ПРЕДЫДУЩУЮ ширину а не изначальную. Просто я думал что она сохраняется в каком-нибудь свойстве какова-нибудь объекта типа window или screen или document и т. д.

Можно написать вот такой простой скрипт:

```
(function(){
    /* Указываем значения при инициализации */
    var beforeResize = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
        /* Используем предыдущие значения */
        console.log(beforeResize.width);

        /* Обновляем значения, которые станут предыдущим для следущего вызова функции */
        beforeResize = {
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight
        }
    })
})()
```

Comment: Логика конечно верна, вот только у нас изменение будет по паре пикселей .... За ответ это вряд ли сойдет, ибо ТС сам не знает чего хочет. Ждем пока переформулирует.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Сею задачу решил практически также. Т. е. функция которая сохраняет текущую ширину а потом вычитает из неё последующую. И это нормально. Просто если бы значение ширины до ресайза где-нить сохранялось автоматом, можно было бы написать всё в одну строчку)